# jQuery UI: Draggable and Droppable(not firing) within a table and its rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

I'm currently using Draggable from jQuery UI to drag selected rows within a table. However, when I'm trying to use Droppable on certain table rows, none of its events fire even though the class `ui-droppable` is added to those specific rows. Note that the table is created dynamically, but the events I am creating are all made when the table is rendered.

So far this works nicely:

```
 $(".files") //this is the class of tbody
            .draggable({
                handle: ".selected",
                start: function () {
                    amDragging = true;
                },
                drag: function (evt) {
                    $('.files .template-folder:not(.selected)').addClass('drag-over');
                },
                helper: function (ui) {
                    var endReturn = '<div>';
                    $('.selected').find('.name').each(function (index, element) {
                        endReturn = endReturn + ' ' + $(this).text();
                    });
                    amDragging = true;
                    console.log(amDragging);
                    return endReturn + '</div>';
                },
                cursorAt: {
                    top: -10,
                    left: -10
                },
                scroll: false,
                stop: function (evt) {
                    $('.files .template-folder').removeClass('drag-over');
                }
            });
```

However this does not trigger:

```
 $(".files .template-folder").droppable({
           drop: function(event, ui) { 
             console.log("dropped");
           }
 });
```

Basically, what I am trying to do, is drag the rows with the class `.selected` onto rows with the class `.template-folder` and fire an event once thats done. Is there anything going wrong with that code that I am missing, or is there a simple work around it?

I have tried binding `dragover` on `.template-folder` but that doesnt fire with Draggable, only with dragged text etc.

This is what the table html looks like:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm really stuck on this.

Comment: Hi, an image of the HTML is not much helpful since we can't even copy it... try to make a demo in stack snippet or jsfiddle demonstrating the problem so that others can play with it

Comment: @T J, hey, I was gonna try recreate the problem when I got home since what goes behind creating the table is massive and runs mostly in PHP. Ill update my question when I do so, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ui on table elements you should use
ui helper:'clone', that will make elements position:absolute

NOTE: default ui-draging is position relative and position relative is not supported for table elements.

Try: activeClass option
https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-activeClass
probably it will fix your issue.